# Overriding standard C library functions in C++ program

Tags: c++

I wanted to know how does the compiler/linker selects from the 2 printf functions available. One is the user defined and the other is the standard c library implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printf(const char* c, ...) { 
return 0;
}

int main() {
printf("\n Hello World\n");
}
```

I know what overloading is but here both implementations have same signatures. Basically I don't understand this concept of **'overriding'** of functions.
Does this somehow violate ODR? Is this a well defined C++ program or can it have UB on some platforms?

Comment: @Marek R Is overriding different from overloading?

Comment: This isn't overloading, in C++ allows you to override a member function by implementing a derived alternative.  C does not.

Comment: @VishalSharma In C++ "*overriding*" refers to overriding of virtual member functions in derived classes. There is only "*overloading*" and "*replacement*" for global functions. "*Replacing*" of functions is only possible in very specific instances, i.e. with `operator new` and `operator delete`, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/replacement.functions

Comment: Look up the concept of *weak symbols*. It's not a part of the standard C++. The builtin `printf` is "weak", so the linker overrides it with your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding is a completely different concept from overloading. 
You override *a virtual member function*.

No overloading takes place here.

What actually happens is you are defining `printf` with the exact same signature as `stdio.h` declares. So it's the same function (with "C" linkage!). You are just providing its definition. It is undefined behaviour to define a standard library function, except for those functions explicitly mentioned as user-replaceable.

Comment: From your answer, I understand that this is neither overloading nor overriding, right? How does the linker just ignores the definition in standard library? Is printf one of those functions which are mentioned as user-replaceable? How many such functions are there?

Comment: @VishalSharma Unix linkers normally ignore multiple definitions found in libraries (but not in objects). Printf is not user-replaceable. AFAIR only variants of ´operator new` and `operator delete` are.

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior because it defines a name in a reserved context. [[extern.names]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/extern.names#4) of the C++17 standard draft states that function signatures with external linkage from the C standard library are reserved and [[reserved.names]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/reserved.names#2) says that defining a name in a reserved context causes undefined behavior.